# How to completely reset blender or find missing files

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, extrude, error

Something is wrong with blender and it's preventing me from extruding so I reinstalled blender twice but it still won't fix. I'd their any other way you can reset blender?

Comment: Well you can load factory settings. That being said it'd be a super weird bug if just extruding didn't work

Comment: @WhatAMesh yeah I've reloaded the factory settings but still nothing changed. So far I've only tried extruding so there may be other problems. The error message is on my other question if you want to see it though.

Comment: @Arthur.M which version of Blender are you using?

Comment: @Hexbob6 I was using 2.79 when it stopped working then I installed 2.79b but it was still broken. I checked on blender 2.8 and it was all fine.

Comment: @Arthur.M Hmm strange, is it all extrusion behaviours that aren't working? For example, pressing the `E` key, using the mesh tools options in the properties panel (whilst inside of edit mode) or selecting the vertices due for extruding and pressing `CTRL`+`LMB`? Did it work previously but then suddenly stop working?

Comment: @Hexbob6 Somebody told me how to fix it! I had to go to one of the user data files and rename a file called 2.79 to 2.79-bad and that reset everything! Thanks for your help anyway though!

Comment: No problem, @Arthur.M , glad you got it sorted! If you think it is something obscure that would benefit others, you could write a quick answer explaining how you fixed it? :)